# Конкурс (на, за) что-то?

Tags: грамматика

Написал вот такой текст

*Хотел начать конкурс **за** этот вопрос, [но не вижу кнопки].*
Засомневался в предлоге.

Answer (score 1):

Участник или предмет конкурса (кто или что конкурирует) обычно выступают без предлога, поэтому можно предположить, что
предлоги в выражениях о конкурсе закрепились в результате сокращения более развёрнутых выражений, в которых они относились, например, к *предмету* конкурса или *награде* по его результатам.

(предлог "на" - на предмет того, кто лучший или самый подходящий)

- Конкурс претендентов на замещение вакансии.
- Конкурс, проводимый на предмет замещения вакансии.
- Результат сокращения: Конкурс **на** замещение вакансии.

(предлог "за" - конкурс соревнующихся за звание, почётное право - редкий случай)

- Конкурс молодых специалистов, соревнующихся за звание "лучший по профессии".
- Результат сокращения: Конкурс **за** право называться "лучшим по профессии".

Comment: Да, это все понятно. Но у меня случай такой, что "соревнуются" за приз. И тут нет претендентов... Вообще говоря, конкурс - достаточно кривой перевод английского bounty, но другого перевода не придумали. Но это конкурс особого типа, все вами сказанное про обычные конкурсы здесь мало применимо. (+) Посмотрите вообще, в чм смысл такого конкурса на этом ресурсе. Может оно и проянится, в чем мои затруднения.

Comment: @behemothus Может вместо "конкурса" луче было бы перевести как "приз"?

Comment: @behemothus А [здесь](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=bounty&l1=1) есть еще варианты: "премия" и даже "призовая премия".

Comment: Это слово обычно означает "вознаграждение" за что-то (от истребления волков до отлова преступника), в беллетристике бывает на "конкурсной" основе: награда, назначенная за чью-то голову, достаётся тому, кто первый управился. Что-то вроде "гонки за приз(ом)".

Comment: Да, я знаю варианты перевода. Потому и говорю, что выбранный - кривой, но возможно самый прямой из возможных. "Призовая премия" - это уже перебор. Остальное понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще говоря, бывают конкурсы (кого/чего) пианистов, детского рисунка и конкурсы на (что): на замещение должности, на лучшее исполнение произведения, на лучшую роль.

Но кажется, раньше предлог ЗА также использовался, но сейчас, наверное, устарел: "Кроме того, комиссия предлагает учредить конкурс за лучшие сочинения по хирургии".

Comment: Но здесь не "кого/чего", а "ради чего". Речь-то о награде. Вот на замещение должности - это уже ближе к теме.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если приз "этот вопрос".
   Хотел начать конкурс за **право ответить на** этот вопрос.
2. Если приз другой и будет вручен за правильный ответ на "этот вопрос".
   Этот вопрос хотел сделать конкурсным, но не вижу кнопки.

Comment: Конкурс за право ответить? Ну что за ерунда! Ответить могут только избранные? На конкурсные вопросы здесь, как правило, нет правильных и неправильных ответов, всё гораздо сложнее.

Comment: Извините, а Вы прочитали предшествующий текст: 1. Если приз "этот вопрос".? Мой ответ никоим образом не относится к правилам конкурсов на этом сайте.

Comment: Ну во-первых, речь шла именно о конкурсах на сайте, а во-вторых, Ваша ситуация какая-то оторванная от реальности. Если Вы ставите вопросительный знак в своём комментарии, точку из своего пункта надо перед ним опустить.

Comment: "... речь шла именно о конкурсах на сайте..." - где это написано в вопросе?  Извините, я не телепат, чтобы узнать, что думал автор, и как воспринимает этот текст один из читателей. С знаком вопроса действительно есть неувязка - глаз спотыкается. В цитатах я обязан сохранять исходную пунктуацию, поэтому точка обязательна. Скорее не точку надо выкинуть, а вставить кавычки, от двоеточия, до знака вопроса [после точки :-)].

Comment: *С**о** знаком* правильно. Нет, точку не надо сохранять, она не элемент цитаты, от лукавого её сохранять. После точки тем более кавычку не ставят, только перед. Для меня очевидно, что имел в виду Бегемотус, если спросить его, он это подтвердит.